# Mutex implementation in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, mutex

I'm currently learning about thread synchronization in Java and chose to do some tests of my own. The program contains a few threads that access a method to add 1 to a shared int and print which thread just used the method and what the new value of x is. The goal is to have the threads count up from 0 to 10 and print it in the right order like this:

```
public int addNumbers() {
    x++;
    if (x >= 10) {
        running = false;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Thread:

```
private class RunThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println(addNumbers());
        }
    }
}
```

In order to create Mutex I've used an ReentrantLock which I've played around with but I have some questions:

Why does this guarantee Mutex and makes the thread print the numbers in the right order...:

```
lock.lock();
System.out.println(addNumbers());
lock.unlock();
```

... while this does not?:

```
public int addNumbers() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        x++;
        if (x >= 10) {
            running = false;
        }
        return x;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

It looks like it does the same thing to me. And why does it suddenly work when I add a Thread.sleep in the method?:

```
public int addNumbers() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        x++;
        if (x >= 10) {
            running = false;
        }
        return x;
    } finally {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

I've tried to read up on it online, but it just doesn't make any sense to me.
Please help and be kind, I've only just started to learn about multithreading.

Expected "right" results (Counts up normally):

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

11

Wrong results:

2

3

1

4

5

7

6

9

8

10

Entire code:

```
public class LockTest {
    int x = 0;
    boolean running = true;
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LockTest t1 = new LockTest();
    }

    public LockTest() {
        init();
    }

    public int addNumbers() {
        x++;
        if (x >= 10) {
            running = false;
        }
        return x;
    }

    private void init() {
        Thread t1 = new RunThread();
        Thread t2 = new RunThread();
        Thread t3 = new RunThread();
        t1.setName("t1");
        t2.setName("t2");
        t3.setName("t3");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }

    private class RunThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                lock.lock();
                System.out.println(this.getName() + ": " + addNumbers());
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, if adding `sleep` "fixes" something like this, then your happens-before relationships aren't fully specified.

Comment: Define what the "right order" is. What do you expect to happen and why, precisely? What happens instead, precisely? My expectation, in all cases, is an undetermined order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one case, you have

```
lock.lock();
System.out.println(this.getName() + ": " + addNumbers());
lock.unlock();
```

So, all threads want to execute these lines concurrently, but only one can do it at a time. So the first thread gets the lock, thus preventing other threads to get it, then increments and prins the value, then releases the lock. Another thread can then get the lock, increment and print, then release the lock. You thus get the values printed in ascending order.

In the second case you only have

```
 System.out.println(this.getName() + ": " + addNumbers());
```

So, all threads can execute this concurrently. **Inside addNumbers**, though, the threads must acquire a lock to increment the number. So the number is incremented in the right order, but since the print is not inside the mutex, you have no guarantee of the order. Example:

```
 - Thread 1: acquire the lock
 - Thread 1: increment x (x = 1)
 - Thread 1: read the value returned by addNumbers (= 1) to print it
 - Thread 1: release the lock
 - Thread 2: acquire the lock
 - Thread 2: increment x (x = 2)
 - Thread 2: read the value returned by addNumbers (= 2) to print it
 - Thread 2: release the lock
 - Thread 2: print the read value: 2
 - Thread 1: print the read value: 1
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you very much!